# myFlowPanel has many childFlowPanels, so how to create the same margin for all childFlowPanels without using marginTop on childFlowPanels (GWT)?

Tags: css, gwt

```
//myFlowPanel has many childFlowPanels

myFlowPanel.add(childFlowPanel1);
myFlowPanel.add(childFlowPanel2);
//.. more childs here
```

Then I want each of these childs will have 5px margin gap between them, but I don't want to apply "margin-top" for each child.

Just wondering if there's a way we can just has 1 line of code like this to do all the works like `cellspacing` in `<table>`:

```
myFlowPanel.setFlowPanelSpacing("5px");
```

Mybe we can do at css level, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in CSS:

```
.myPanel div {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What an awesome elegant solution which save me a lot of works. Thank you very much Andrei Volgin.